How can UserName’s ProtectedPersonalData attribute be overridden in ASP.NET Core Identity?
I’m using ASP.NET Core Identity in a Blazor project. I’d like to encrypt the user’s personal data, however, I don’t want to encrypt the UserName. My plan is to use the UserName as an account id rather than the user’s name. The user’s name will instead be held externally to the IdentityUser class and encrypted separately using a different encryption mechanism. This account id, which will be held in UserName, needs to be memorable, but not contain user identifiable data, so won’t need to be encrypted, it will just be like any normal login id. My hope is that, by not encrypting this account id, it will be possible for the user to recover their account under certain scenarios.
I’ve been unable to override the ProtectedPersonalData attribute on UserName.
I’ve added a LookupProtector class that realises ILookupProtector and LookupProtectorKeyRing that realises ILookupProtectorKeyRing.
I’ve added a class called ApplicationUser that inherits from IdentityUser and given it a UserName property without the ProtectedPersonalData attribute …
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user name for this user.
    /// </summary>
    public override string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
}

I’ve modified ApplicationDbContext to use ApplicationUser as a generic type …
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

I’ve modified the call to AddDefaultIdentity to refer to  ApplicationUser instead of IdentityUser and added a call to AddPersonalDataProtection with generic types for LookupProtector and LookupProtectorKeyRing ...
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Stores.ProtectPersonalData = true;
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
  .AddPersonalDataProtection<LookupProtector, LookupProtectorKeyRing>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();

I’ve replaced all other references to IdentityUser in my code to ApplicationUser, for example, the instances of UserManager and SignInManager use ApplicationUser as their generic type instead of IdentityUser ...
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

I’ve tried scaffolding the User class in case that does something different to what I’ve done manually. I needed to click ‘+’ then type in the name of the ApplicationDbContext by hand and also check an unwanted file ‘Account/Lockout’ to get it to proceed, but even then it failed with a build error, even though my code builds fine with a normal build. The build error was, "There was an error running the selected code generator: Failed to compile the project in memory"
Scaffold settings:

I’ve also dropped the existing database, rolled back all migrations (including the original Identity migration) and then added a single new migration for all models created to-date using these commands …
dotnet ef database drop
dotnet ef migrations remove (multiple calls)
dotnet ef migrations add CreateTables
dotnet ef database update

However, now when I register a user I see that the method LookupProtector.Protect is called with data that seems to be from the UserName or NormalizedUserName.
Is it possible to override the default protected behaviour in a class derived from IdentityUser or do I just need to find a way to work with the defaults? Thanks for any help you can offer.
I could try to work around this by adding a UserId property to ApplicationUser and attempt to leave the UserName mostly ignored, but I’d like to find a solution that feels more ‘correct’ if I can.

The NormalizedUserName is not marked as Protected. Are you sure that UserManager.FindByNameAsync() not already does what you want? It's unclear what "recover their account" is. Don't go too much DIY on security.

@HenkHolterman, thanks for your feedback. I'm still trying to work out the details of the solution.  When I look inside the database I can see that the NormalizedUserName is also encrypted, even though it doesn't carry the ProtectedPersonalData attribute. I'm planning to use end-to-end encryption, so I'm trying to avoid having any unencrypted keys stored in the server's database. Instead, keys will be held elsewhere and accessed using the user's unique id.

@HenkHolterman, thinking through the recovery scenarios, something close to the standard ForgotPassword recovery might work when the user forgets their password. Recovery when the user forgets their unique id is more difficult. The AES keys required to decrypt protected data using LookupProtector will not be accessible whilst the user has forgotten their unique id. I'll keep thinking through this. There may be ways to provide recovery of a forgotten user id even if it's encrypted, which means that I can hold it within UserName and leave it encrypted in the server's database.
